# Why doesn't Rust release references to variables as early as possible?

Tags: rust

Consider the following case:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut inc = || {
        count += 1;
        println!("`count`: {}", count);
    };
    inc();
    // let _reborrow = &count;    ERROR
    inc();
}
```

If I don't delete the commented out line

```rust
let _reborrow = &count;
```

The compiler will say: cannot borrow `count` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable.

Why wouldn't the compiler think that I released the mutable reference to `count` after `inc()`, and then released it immediately after acquiring the immutable reference to `count` with the line `let _reborrow = &count`, and then acquiring the immutable reference to `count` again with `inc()`?

I would like to get an explanation for the above problem, if the above idea is followed then the above code will compile[without commenting that line], while the following situation will result in a compilation error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut inc = || {
        count += 1;
        println!("`count`: {}", count);
    };
    inc();
    let _reborrow = &count;
    inc();
    println!("{}", _reborrow);
}
```

Comment: As early as possible is *after* the second call to `inc` not in between calls, the closure needs to hold on to a mutable reference to be able to mutate `count`!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64948040/442760) answer your question?

Comment: The closure closes over all references (it creates an ad-hoc struct that contains all necessary references) as long as the closure is in scope, it has to hold on to the references.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think it's related to my question to some extent, but I noticed the `by design` in the high praise answer, and my question was asking exactly why it was designed that way。

Comment: To give another answer (not related to this code): any value that has a custom `Drop` implementation will _never_ be dropped early by the compiler. This is so it's completely predictable when custom drop code runs.

Comment: Your proposed semantics is incompatible with being able to pass the closure as a value which is one of their key features.

Comment: @cafce25 `Your proposed semantics is incompatible with being able to pass the closure as a value which is one of their key features.` Can you give an example?

Comment: No, I obviously can't give an example of something impossible. How does a function which takes an arbitrary closure know which reference, to what, to aquire, *without already being passed a reference*? Can you give an example?

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks for your reply, I may not have thought this through, let me take some more time to think about it.

Comment: @KatoMegumi Consider that the closure is allowed to keep its own state, and the correctness of the closure's implementation may rely on the assumption that the referent of a captured immutable reference will not be modified by other code, which is a valid assumption as Rust guarantees this with its aliasing model. What you are proposing breaks this model, and therefore renders one of the _primary benefits_ of the borrow checker completely void.

Comment: I must say I am also a bit lost in understanding what you ask: `_reborrow` *is* a reference, to an immutable value (no `mut` keyword when you declare it), yet the value *does* get mutated during the reference's lifetime. One extra step (which you haven't asked) is: if you declared `_reborrow` as a referene to a mutable value (`_reborrow = &mut count`), you would still have an error but with a different message: rust does not allow to have two active mutable borrows at the same time. Are you asking "why doesn't the compiler understand my example" ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, I was once trying to ask why the compiler couldn't understand my example.

Answer (score 0):

> and then acquiring the immutable reference to `count` again with `inc()`?

How, exactly? How would you communicate to the closure to acquire the reference?

The closure must keep the reference for itself, because no one can hand it a copy of it. Remember the closure could be unknown, for example returned from a function, and then there is no way to "pause" and "resume" its ownership of the reference.

Comment: For example (just as an example) maintain an `immutable_reference_count` for each variable as well as a `mutable_reference_count` like this, and then have `mutable_reference_count` +1 if there's an immutable reference in the closure, and -1 immediately after `inc()`.

Comment: @KatoMegumi This won't be a zero-cost abstraction, so a non-starter.

Comment: @KatoMegumi This is also impossible in the general case: where would you keep those variables, and how would the closure know to increment and decrement them?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply. I realized that this is not a zero-cost abstraction. What I just thought may be similar to the implementation of shared_ptr in C++, such as alloc a space on the heap for the SharedPtr class to store count and so on. Then the closure uses the reference of this variable to access its member variables to increment and decrement them.

Comment: @KatoMegumi `Rc` and `Arc` are the Rust reference-counted smart pointers. If that's the behavior you need, use one of those. They work like you describe. Asking for references in Rust to work like `shared_ptr` makes about as much sense as asking C++ references to work like `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, thank you for your reply!

Comment: @KatoMegumi Also, `RefCell` implements the dynamic borrowing you described. So `Rc<RefCell>`.